# BCNF and 4NF for Database

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

So I started out with these 3 tables and was told to modify them into BCNF and 4NF:

> PRIVATE_SESSION  (Trainer, Phone, Email, Fee, ClientLastName,
>   ClientFirstName, ClientPhone, ClientEmail, Date, Time)
>
> CLUB_MEMBERSHIP  (ClientNumber, ClientLastName, ClientFirstName,
>   ClientPhone, ClientEmail, MembershipType, EndingDate, Street, City,
>   State, Zip)
>
> CLASS (ClassName, Trainer, StartDate, EndDate, Cost)

*Also suggest a new table to keep track of client, the classes subscribed, and the amount paid while still keeping everything in BCNF and 4NF

=================================================================

So, I turned them into these 7 tables to try and comply with the BCNF and 4NF. Question is...is this even remotely correct? The definition of BCNF is satisfied if every determinate is a candidate key, which it looks like they are. 4NF is satisfied if it contains no multivalued dependencies I believe...and I tried separating the tables so they would not

#### TRAINER

```
ID (primary key),
TrainerLastName,
TrainerFirstName,
TrainerEmail,
TrainerPhone
```

#### TRAINER_SESSION

```
ID (primary key),
ID (foreign key from CLIENT_INFO.ID)
TrainingStartTime,
TrainingStartDate,
TrainingFee
```

#### CLIENT_INFO

```
ID (primary key),
ClientLastName,
ClientFirstName,
ClientPhone,
ClientEmail,
```

#### MEMBER_ADDRESS

```
ID (primary key),
ID (foreign key to CLIENT_INFO.ID),
State,
City,
Street,
Zip
```

#### MEMBERSHIP_INFO

```
ID (primary key),
ID (foreign key to CLIENT_INFO.ID),
MembershipType,
MembershipStartDate,
MembershipEndDate
```

#### CLUB_CLASS

```
ID (primary key),
TrainerID (foreign key to  TRAINER.ID),
ClassName,
ClassStartDate,
ClassEndDate,
ClassCost
```

#### CLASS_ENROLLMENT

```
(ClassID, MemberID) composite primary keys
TotalClasses,
TotalPaid
```

Comment: Why does `TRAIN_SESSION` contain `TrainerFirstName`, `TrainerLastName`? (same goes for `CLUB_CLASS`)  It doesn't look to be 2nf to me because of that.

Comment: Because I was silly and copied it wrong from what I did earlier. Of course that only applies to those two..anything else was..or is a mistake rather

Comment: I don't see the point of `CLASS_EXPENSE`.  First of all, the original tables do not model this data - are you supposed to add new concepts to the original model?  Second of all, instead of storing the aggregate data directly (AmountofClassesTaken, TotalAmountPaid), you should model Class_Member_Enrollment(ClassID, MemberID), and sum these records to get the totals.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I forgot to add we were supposed to also suggest a new table to keep track of client, the classes subscribed, and the amount paid while still keeping everything in BCNF and 4NF. I like the composite key idea though :D

Comment: @user2503165 - So the second part of my comment still stands - you are not modelling which members are enrolled in which classes.

Comment: If I get where you are going, you mean to change it to CLASS_MEMBER_ENROLLMENT(ClassID,MemberID) <--being the composite primary keys and something like ClassSum as well as Total Amount?

Comment: No, you don't need to track the number of classes taken or the total cost.  Each record in CLASS_MEMBER_ENROLLMENT records one instance of a member taking a class.  So if you counted those records, you'd know how many classes a member took.  You can use ClassID to join to CLUB_CLASS, where you can get CLUB_CLASS.ClassCost.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you're not sure it's right, ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For a more recent version of the proposed schema (revision 11)

<sup>Since the schema is going to be revised, it is going to be hard to keep answers in sync with the current edition of the schema.  Please bear that in mind when reviewing any given answer.</sup>

Class Enrollment has the Total Classes and Total Paid fields which are not appropriate.  The table should be key-only unless members can negotiate a per-class fee (discount) for the class compared with the list price (in which case it needs a 'fee paid') attribute.  The totals should be calculated when necessary, or stored in a separate table independent of the specific class.

Membership Info and Member Address have acquired two columns called ID, which is confusing.  Presumably, the second should be labelled Client ID in each table (that would be more reasonable).  The question now arising is 'what is the cardinality of the relationship between Membership Info and Client Info, and between Member Address and Client Info?'  For addresses, can a member exist without the address being known?  Can a member have two or more addresses?  If the answer to either of those is 'yes', then the design is OK.  If the answer is 'no', it is not clear that you need both Client Info and Member Address.  Similarly with Membership Info and Client Info.

Trainer Session has two ID fields.  The second is presumably Client ID, but it also needs a Trainer ID to identify which trainer ran the session.

#### For the original version of the proposed schema (revision 6)

<sup>Or a 'close to original' version of the proposed schema.</sup>

You've clearly not created a non-loss decomposition since the 'class name' element is missing.

The Class Expense table has no counterpart in the original tables.

It is not clear that the Trainer table is warranted from the original tables, though I agree with most of the fields.  The Fee attribute is misplaced here, though.

The Train Session table is missing attributes, more or less however you slice and dice things.  If it is meant to represent the private sessions, then you're missing trainer ID and client ID and fee.  If it is meant to be generic with public (club) sessions, then you need a table somewhere that records the private sessions.

The triad of Member Info, Client Info and Membership Info are confused and/or confusing.  Without supplemental information about how the database is supposed to handle the information, it is hard to know what's best to recommend.  The Member Info table might be better named as Address.  The Membership Info table has no connection to the Client Info table, so memberships are associated with an address but not with a person (and people are not associated with addresses).

The Club Class table is OK, I think.

Classes exist and are taught by trainers, but no-one is ever recorded as going to the classes.

Comment: I've gone back and made a bunch of edits, although there is a good chance I messed something up even more. The idea with the different tables(Client_INFO, MEMBER_ADDRESS, and MEMBER_INFO) was to seperate some multivalue dependancies...but something I did not mention was that in order to have a private trainer session you have to be a member of the club, but it is just an added option. The Club facilities(aka the classes) require membership as well but I count the private sessions and the facility classes as different things.

Comment: Or in other words...When a person registers and becomes a member of this Club they have two avenues open to them. They can either hire an independent personal trainer for a nominal fee on their own time (Trainer_Session)...or they can take a class offered by the club and the same trainers for some other fee (Club_class).

Comment: I know and I'm really really sorry I keep revising it but I didn't want it to take up 10000000000 lines of the page. So, going to CLIENTINFO and MEMBERADDRESS the reason I seperated the two was because I assumed it would have a multivalue dependency smacked in there. For MEMBERSHIP INFO the reason I made a separate table for MEMBERSHIP INFO was because (in my mind) a membership into a club did not logically go with general data about a client, even if there is an indirect relationship there. Would it be better to just combine these tables?

Comment: Going with what you said before..sure I could have a person without an address but how likely of a scenario would that really be? It seems like a band aid

Comment: I understand the need to edit the schema — but it does complicate the answering process too.  Referencing revisions is a novelty (I've not done it before, or seen anyone else do it), but helps those who come later see what I was talking about.  _To business:_ I think most clubs are likely to insist on an address.  Separating tables that should be joined 1:1 (not 0-or-1:0-or-1 or something else like that) usually just makes life complicated without any benefit.  (Exception: if you have a big column — BLOB or similar — then it may be better to store it separately, but that's physical design.)

Comment: Ah, then I will most likely go back and combine them to make it flow a little better even if it goes against my own logic. Partially because it's true..the extra table does make it more complicated than it needs to be I think. However, I will do that later so thank you for all the help :)